# How to get the dynamic value from solr

Tags: java, solrj

How to get the dynamic value from solr

```
<dynamicField indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="test_*" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
```

I have tried to get the value using the following code :

```
Map<String,String> myMap = (Map<String,String>) result1.get(i).getFieldValue("test_*");
```

This code is not working.

Please let me know how to fetch the dynamic value from solr.